# WordPress category list grouped per letter outputs wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, list

**Desired situation**

I want to create an overview of all used categories in my website, grouped per letter. My next step is then to columnize these categories.

The output code should look like:

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <h3>A</h3>
        <li>Alfa</li>
        <li>Auto</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <h3>B</h3>
        <li>Beta</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h3>A</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Alfa</li>
                <li>Auto</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h3>B</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Beta</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Current situation**

The code that I now have does output a list, but the output is as follows:

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <h3>A</h3>
        <li>Alfa</li>
        <li>Auto</li>
        <h3>B</h3>
        <li>Beta</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, the code below only creates the list with letters, but no grouped.

```
$param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories = get_categories($cat_args);
if ($categories) {
    $first_letter = null;
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $flag = 0;
        if( $first_letter != substr( $category->name, 0, 1 ) ) {
          $first_letter = substr( $category->name, 0, 1 );
          $flag = 1;
        }
        if( $flag ) {
          echo '<h3>'.$first_letter.'</h3>';
        }
        $args = array(
            "$param_type" => $category->id,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . $category->name . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
wp_reset_query();
```

**Question**

Is there anyone that can help me to get my current situation to the desired situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I don't know if it is the best way to do it, but it worked anyway.
Any suggestions or improvements are still welcome.

```
<?php
$param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
if ($categories) {
    $first_letter = null;
    $group_per_column = 2;
    $i = 0;
    $ic = 0;
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $category_letter = strtoupper(substr($category->name,0,1));

        if( $first_letter != $category_letter ) {
            if ($i%$group_per_column == 0) {
                if ($first_letter != '') echo '</ul></li></ul></div>' . $parent_ul;
                $first_letter = $category_letter;
                $i += 1;
                $ic += 1;
                echo "<div class=\"wrap column_$ic\"><ul class=\"category_list\"><li class=\"$category_letter\"><h2> - $i $category_letter - </h2>";
                echo '<ul>';
            } else {
                if ($first_letter != '') echo '</ul></li></ul>' . $parent_ul;
                $first_letter = $category_letter;
                $i += 1;
                echo "<ul class=\"category_list\"><li class=\"$category_letter\"><h2> - $i $category_letter - </h2>";
                echo '<ul>';
            }
        }
        $args = array(
            "$param_type" => $category->id,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . $category->name . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul></li></ul></div>';
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```